# How to implement Android things/Google assistant on my board

Tags: sdk, android-things

I'm trying to make my personal google assistant, and platform is using i.MX7 as website suggested.

My question is, could I bring it up with my own hardware design? (i might try some other wireless to connect through zigbee/bt/ble/wifi..etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidthings-assistant/#0) step-by-step tutorial and [that](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant) repo.

Answer (score 1):

To make your own Google Assistant IoT device, you should read the documentation for the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/). This will allow you to make calls to the Assistant from any Internet connected device.

The second part of your question, about Android Things, isn't clear about what you want. You can build your own developer board for Android Things, using one of the supported SoMs, but you cannot use a different baseboard altogether. While you can use external wireless modules connected through user-level drivers, you will not be able to do the same at a lower-level. On Android Things boards, like the Raspberry Pi and IMX7, BLE and Wi-Fi are included in the hardware already.